# How to get multiple divs getElementById

Tags: html, getelementbyid

I am trying to get an array of divs on my page and replace some html inside them, but I can get only the first DIV. I used getElementsByName and got the same result.
I'm sure that there is a simple solution, but I can't find it.
Here is my code on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Gt4p2/

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function repl() {
        var x=document.getElementById("post-content").innerHTML;
        var y=x.replace(/Description/g,"<b>Description</b><br/>");  
        for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
               document.getElementById('post-content').innerHTML=y;
        }
}
    onload = repl;
</script>
</head>
<body>

                    <div id="post-content">
                        <p>Description Power: 1W*3pcs LED color: RGB color deterioration, red, yellow, blue, green, white </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="post-content">
                        <p>Description Power: 1W*3pcs LED color: RGB color deterioration, red, yellow, blue, green, white </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="post-content">
                        <p>Description Power: 1W*3pcs LED color: RGB color deterioration, red, yellow, blue, green, white </p>
                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The id attribute is supposed to be unique.  How about changing the divs to be <div class="post-content">  then using document.getElementsByClassName("post-content")?

Comment: I've tried to use "class" but the bug is still there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use getElementsByTagName().

Try this in your fiddle, it'll work:

```
function repl() {
        var x=document.getElementById("post-content").innerHTML;
        var y=x.replace(/Description/g,"<b>Description</b><br/>");
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
               divs[i].innerHTML=y;
        }
}
repl();
```

If you want to use getElementsByName(), note that you must give the DIVs a "name" attribute, not an "id".

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your html markup, use class instead of an id. The id should be unique in your html

`< div class="post-content">

Description Power: 1W*3pcs LED color: RGB color deterioration, red, yellow, blue, green, white

< /div>

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("post-content");`

elements will be an array now.